# Monotone nondecreasing homeo => Lipschitz?

Tags: analysis

If I have a monotone non-decreasing $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [c,d]$ which is also a homeomorphism, is it necessarily Lipschitz? If yes, what would be a good candidate for the Lipschitz constant?

I'm doing some path reparameterizations and this would make things a lot easier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question can be asked with fewer words, since every homeomorphism between closed intervals must be strictly monotone and it clearly has no bearing on the hypothesis whether $f$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, since
\begin{align}
f:[0,1]&\rightarrow [0,1]\newline
x&\mapsto \sqrt{x}
\end{align}
is obviously a monotone homeomorphism, but given $x\in (0,1]$
$$d(f(x),f(0))=|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{0}|=\frac{|x-0|}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{d(x,0)}{\sqrt{x}} $$
show us, that there is now possible $L>0$ such that
$$d(f(x),f(0))\leq L\cdot d(x,0)$$
due to the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\infty$$

Comment: Perhaps is locally Lipchitz almost everywhere?

Comment: @HighGPA If by locally Lipschitz almost everywhere you mean that there is a subset $X\subseteq [a,b]$ such that $[a,b]\setminus X$ is of measure zero and such that for all $x\in X$ there is an open nhood $B(x,\varepsilon_x)$ so that $f_{|B(x,\varepsilon)}$ is Lipschitz. The answer is no. Such an $X$ would be dense, so the $B(x,\varepsilon_x)$ would cover $[a,b]$ and, by compactness, a finite subset would cover $[a,b]$. Hence $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [c,d]$ would be Lipschitz.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say that the example $f(x)=\sqrt x$ seems to be locally Lipschitz except on a finite subset of [0,1].

Answer (score 3):

With $a=c=0$, $b=d=1$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x$ we get a counter-example since $|f(n^{-1})-f(0)|=\sqrt n^{-1}$ and $\frac{|f(n^{—1})-f(0)|}{n^{—1}-0}=\frac{\sqrt n^{-1}}{n^{-1}}=\sqrt n$. ($f$ is continuous, bijective since it's inverse is $f^{-1}(x)=x^2$ which is continuous)